# Change data-percentage attribute everyday

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to change data-percenatage attribute of my element by 6 everyday, but it's not working or i'm doing something wrong. Can someone take a look and tell me what is wrong? I have a few elements with data percentage and i want to change them everyday.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dzisiaj = new Date();
    var dzien = dzisiaj.getDay();
    if(dzien==0)
    {
        var dana = $("#l1").data-percent();
        dana = dana + 6;
        $("#l1").attr("data-percent", dana);
    }
    else if(dzien==1)
    {
        var dana = $("#l1").data-percent();
        dana = dana + 6;
        $("#l1").attr("data-percent", dana);
    }
    else if(dzien==2)
    {
        var dana = $("#l1").data-percent();
        dana = dana + 6;
        $("#l1").attr("data-percent", dana);
    }
    else if(dzien==3)
    {
        var dana = $("#l1").data-percent();
        dana = dana + 6;
        $("#l1").attr("data-percent", dana);
    }
    else if(dzien==4)
    {
        var dana = $("#l1").data-percent();
        dana = dana + 6;
        $("#l1").attr("data-percent", dana);
    }
    else if(dzien==5)
    {
        var dana = $("#l1").data-percent();
        dana = dana + 6;
        $("#l1").attr("data-percent", dana);
    }
    else if(dzien==6)
    {
        var dana = $("#l1").data-percent();
        dana = dana + 6;
        $("#l1").attr("data-percent", dana);
    }
});
```

here is that element in html

```
<span id="l1" class="chart" data-percent="300"> <span class="percent"></span> </span>
```

Comment: `var dana = $("#l1").attr('data-percent')` or use data-api like `var dana = $("#l1").data('percent');` then `$("#l1").data("percent", dana);`

Comment: You have the exact same code in every if branch, and the ifs cover all possibilities so that code doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @ArunPJohny: No, you can't use `data` to set a `data-*` attribute.

Comment: Arun P Johny it's almost working but it shoulwd be 306 and what i get is 3006 and i don't know why.

Juhana because it dosen't matter for me which day is it but i didn't know how to change attr daily i only know how to change it by days :P that's why it's the same code in every if

Comment: *"Can someone take a look and tell me what is wrong?"* Well for a start, what do you think `$("#l1").data-percent();` does? Because what it does is take the `data` property from the jQuery object, then attempt to call a function called `percent`, and then try to subtract the result of the call from the `data` property's value.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes... that is why I changed both the getter and the setter versions

Comment: @ArunPJohny: You're assuming the attribute isn't used for anything else (for instance, something that renders a progress bar or something)...

Comment: here is my site http://autocleanika.pl/index.html i want to change these number at the bottom everyday by some number

Comment: because you are doing a string concatenation not numeric addition... `var dana = +$("#l1").attr('data-percent') || 0`

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your code

1. Reading the attribute `data-percent` is wrong, you are reading teh `data` property value of jQuery object(which is not there) then is subtracting the value returned by `percent` method(which I'm guessing is not there resulting in an error)
2. The attribute value is a string, you need to convert it to nemeric to do the addition so

Try

```
var dzisiaj = new Date();
var dzien = dzisiaj.getDay();

var dana = +$("#l1").attr('data-percent') || 0;
dana += 6;
$("#l1").attr("data-percent", dana);
```

Answer (score -1):

Since `getDay()` returns a number, multiply it by 6 and then sum it up!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dana = parseInt($("#l1").data('percent'), 10);
    dana += (new Date()).getDay() * 6;
    $("#l1").data('percent', dana);
});
```

Comment: Well i don't want it to multiply by day. For me days dosen't matter but i don't know how to change value daily i only know how to change it by day